# How to store a char arrays text in a string?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

ref:c++ example code at bottom from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740120(v=vs.85).aspx
I have a char array

```
char RecvBuf[1024];
```

which gets filled up on receiving UDP message.
How do I store it in a std::string variable  like `string str;` so that I can return a string from my function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this constructor of `std::string`:

```
string ( const char * s, size_t n );
```

Basically, if `RecvBuf` is a standard (text) "string", it's OK just to make

```
std::string str( RecvBuf );
```

but this will copy all `char`s, until `\0` is hit.

---

And as this buffer stores raw bytes, received from a socket, you should expect `\0` bytes.

When you receive the data, you'll know it's size. So, just use

```
std::string str( RecvBuff, buff_len );
```